# I can't use ListView when I am extending my class to ActionBarActivity. I can only access ListView when I extend to ListActivity. Any

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

**My activity**: it is showing me two errors "Required: android.widget.ListView"
I imported the ListView widget already to my Activity so I dont understand what's the issue.

```
package com.example.test.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.List;


public class HomepageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Parse.initialize(this, "dcAMNT7HVOmOw0JDMelkg5UDr388O3xSgICiSK3N", "1aHIAldsUScxlbkWGkoyvHoHWM9YEtpTb6QIijrb");

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        // show user the homepage status
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Status");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> status, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    //success
                    mStatus = status;
                    StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mStatus);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    //there was a problem, Alert user

                }
            }
        });

    } else {
        // show the login screen
        Intent takeUserToLoginScreen = new Intent(HomepageActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(takeUserToLoginScreen);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.updateStatus:
            //take user to update status activity

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateStatusActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;

        case R.id.logoutUser:
            //log out the user
            ParseUser.logOut();

            //take user back to login screen
            Intent takeUserToLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(takeUserToLogin);

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
}
```

My layout which I changed from .android to @+id...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just changed that, and that is not the issue. It is still giving me this problem: "Required: android.widget.ListView" and "Found: android.view.View"

Comment: Do this..final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your code uses the default ListView implementation using ListActivity. What you need to do is create a custom ListView like this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And your activity...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);


ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

Parse.initialize(this, "dcAMNT7HVOmOw0JDMelkg5UDr388O3xSgICiSK3N",    "1aHIAldsUScxlbkWGkoyvHoHWM9YEtpTb6QIijrb");

ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null) {
    // show user the homepage status
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Status");
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> status, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //success
                mStatus = status;
                StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(getApplicationContext (), mStatus);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                //there was a problem, Alert user

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am trying to find the new ListView with the id but it is not working. public class HomepageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        ListView listView = new ListView(findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Do this..ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list); instead of what you've done. Also your ListView layout should have android:id="@+id/list" . Please see my code carefully.

Comment: That got solved but now I have an error when I findbyid it tells me Required: android.widget.ListView. I already imported that. and also "variable listView is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.

Comment: mStatus = status;
                        StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mStatus);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

Comment: Edit your main post with your new code because it is really difficult to read it properly here.

Comment: Also on the top, when I extend ActionBarActivity (It is like scratched on the middle, I am not sure what that means)

Comment: Like I said change the android:id of your listView in your layout to android:id="@+id/list". Also, in your Activity, do ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);, NOT (R.android.id.list) . I have also edited my answer.

Comment: Can you edit your main post with your new Activity and Layout code again?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use ListView when I am extending my class to ActionBarActivity

Yes, you can.

> Now that I am using ListView, the action bar on the top doesn't show

You need to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`, given that you appear to be using `appcompat-v7`. Then, to retrieve your `ListView`, you call `findViewById()`, just like you do for any other widget. In your case, it would be `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`, given your `ListView` `android:id` value.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/ActionBar) with an `ActionBarActivity` that is hosting a `ListView.`

Answer (score 0):

You can extend from ActionBarActivity and have a ListView.  Just add the list view and instead of using setListAdapter(), do:

```
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    //populate items
    items.add(String1)....
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_listview_header, listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new YourListViewAdapter(this,  items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```